# Jpanels overlapping when replaced on a Jframe?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am very new to coding with Java and coding in general but with that said I decided to get some practice by making a very basic game with the knowledge I have accumulated thus far.

I am trying to make the classic brick breaker game and have a JPanel being recreated in order to update the image on the JFrame however it seems that the previous iterations of the JPanel remain even after I removalAll or revalidate etc

ex:

```
//in main method
    while(true){
        update();
    }


    public static void update(){

    DrawScreen refresh = new DrawScreen(bricks, paddle, ball);
    mainscreen.add(refresh);
    mainscreen.revalidate();
    mainscreen.repaint();

}
```

Comment: So where is `removalAll`?

Answer (score 0):

For my particular problem I figured out that I was incorrectly using setContentPane() in another section of my code and that by changing that I only needed

```
mainscreen.setContentPane(refresh);
mainscreen.revalidate();
```

for it to work correctly